# Maliit keyboard for Windows - build error

Tags: windows, qt, keyboard, virtual, qt5

Following this [link](https://wiki.maliit.org/Documentation/Installing), I built the Maliit for windows but I get the error which says

> QDBusContext : No Such file or Directory.

Using git I downloaded the source which is mentioned in the Linux section, since there was no separate link for that. And since DBus is not available for Windows, they have asked to disable it in CONFIG, which I faithfully followed, yet when compiling it's including the Dbus files. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am using Qt 5.

Comment: why don't you include code and ask what issue you are facing instead of showing link only.

Comment: I am just building that source which i downloaded from the git. And there are ceratin .cpp files which uses QDBusContext, which has support for linux and not for windows. I added the CONFIG +=disable-dbus while qmake and i get that above mentioned error.

Comment: According to the [NEWS file](https://gitorious.org/maliit/maliit-framework/blobs/master/NEWS) `disable-dbus` option has been removed. It seems that build instructions are outdated. May be you should ask authors.

Answer (score 0):

While going through document i found that QtDBus module is a Unix-only library that you can use to perform Inter-Process Communication using the D-Bus protocol.

Please refer this link for documentation:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtdbus.html

and also have a look on this link: 
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20263